# Event reciever(email generation functionality not working on production) but working on dev

Tags: email, event-receivers, production

i have an event receiver(which has item adding,added events)  based on a condition i have set the email to get generated in item added event, the email is getting generated on my dev machine but when i deployed it in the production it does generate email..any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post the code which is sending the emails? Have you configured and checked the Outgoing SMTP server in Central Administration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now. Few values were getting null values so I put conditions for all those values.

```
string client = (string)properties.ListItem["Client"];

//replaced by 

string client = ""; 
if (properties.ListItem["Client"] != null)
{
    client = (string)properties.ListItem["Client"];
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer as soon as you the system allows you to